# End of the world movie where only ‘bad’ people are left and a blue monster is chasing main characters

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

End of the world. Main characters are two males. No one is left on Earth, but the few people they run into all seem to be bad.

They meet an old man who invites them into his apartment he offers them some food, like cookies and milk/tea or something. Then they realize the food has been drugged and the old man has dead bodies in his apartment. They escape this scenario somehow.

Also, the entire time there is a blue man chasing them wherever they go, basically a body builder in blue paint. I feel like the movie is British or Irish.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This sounds like *[SOS: Save Our Skins](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2998118/)*, a comedy/sci-fi adventure about the end of the world from 2014.

The main characters are two British men who were attending a sci-fi con in New York. According to the IMDB summary:

> [They] wake up in New York City only to find that the entire human
> race has vanished. But as they explore the seemingly empty world
> before them, Ben and Stephen soon realize they're not alone after
> all... Juggling sci-fi, comedy and horror, SOS: Save Our Skins sends
> Ben and Stephen on a desperate journey to find their loved ones,
> escape the jaws of death and work out why they're one of the few
> remaining people on Earth. But the answer to the mystery is bigger,
> crazier and more apocalyptic than they could ever have imagined, and
> puts the fate of the planet into their very stupid hands.

- the tag-line of the film was "What if the last people left on Earth were idiots?"

They do indeed meet an old man who tries to drug them as described in the question, and are pursued by a "Blue Monster", as well as a creepy image that appears on TVs, and a psychotic biker-chick. I show the Blue Monster below, in case it jogs the OP's memory.

[image: Blue Monster from "SOS"]

Comment: I think you're right, it is SOS Save Our Skins. At first I thought he was referring to 28 Days because of the old man reference but the blue man isn't there. They're basically the same stories but instead of zombies, they use a blue man creature. Too many movies are doing zombies, over and over. It's got old ten years ago but they still do it.

Comment: Yes, this is it! This has been bugging me for 5+ years. Thank you! I first grabbed the dvd for this in a dollar movie bin, watched it and immediately misplaced it. Researching it online never gave me any answers because the main characters and plot are somewhat similar to Simon Pegg’s End of the World. Anyway, I just ordered the dvd to see if this one was as enjoyable as I remember. Thanks again!